# Call a method in a drawer fragment from the base activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I need to call method methodX from fragmentY, which is a drawer from action bar sherlock which means it is not called dynamically. and methodX is called from activityZ.

i set the tag on fragmentY like this:

```
private static final String TAG = "fragmentY";
```

and i called methodX on activityZ like this:

```
fragmentY fragment = (fragmentY ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentY");
fragment.methodX(arg1, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

i also set the fragment on the id like this:

```
android:id="@+id/fragYid"
```

then i called methodX on activityZ like this:

```
fragmentY fragment = (fragmentY ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById("fragYid");
fragment.methodX(arg1, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

but both returns a null pointer exception. so i guess it doesn't see the fragment? but it compiles so i'm really confused right now.

Comment: Jsut keep a instance of your fragment in the Activity and call it

Comment: Sorry, but isn't that what i did on "fragmentY fragment = ..."?

Comment: Where do you add your fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how:

Key is to declare the fragment globally and instantiate it in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Drawer Fragment method as public:

**For Eg:**

*public* void flipMethodLeft(float scrollProgressPercent)

call this drawer fragment from activity:

```
 CardsFragment cf = new CardsFragment();
 cf.flipMethodLeft(80.00f);
```